# Can i restore a previous version of my SharePoint 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I did some faulty modification to my workflow 2013 inside SharePoint designer 2013 for our SharePoint online site. and i want to restore the previous version of my workflow , but can anyone advice if this is possible inside SharePoint designer? as inside SharePoint designer i did not find any option to do so? also the workflow is not showing inside "All Files", as follow:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported since there is no version history for **SharePoint 2013 workflow** in SharePoint Designer 2013.

The **Workflow** catalog is not showing under “All Files” probably because you have never used **SharePoint 2010 workflow** in this site before. The Workflow folder will be automatically generated once you have (or have tried to) publish a SharePoint 2010 workflow to this site.

But still, this method does not apply to SharePoint 2013 workflow since this catalog does not store SharePoint 2013 workflows.

Comment: ok thanks for the info, so in other words i can not restore a workflow 2013?

Comment: @SharePointTestDev As far as I know, no. Your last chance would be previous versions in List settings > Workflow Settings. But if you have published or run the workflow successfully, there won’t be any additional records here.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps, seems this is doable :

Here’s how to revert to a previous version:

1. In the left pane of SharePoint Designer, click the little pin icon next to **All Files**.
2. Once All Files is expanded, scroll down and expand out your folder called **Workflows**. Note that if you have not actually created any workflows yet, you will not have this folder. Each workflow will be a “subfolder” under workflows. One weird little thing to point out also is that if you changed the name of any workflow after you created it, that new name will not show here, only the original name of each workflow will show in this list.
3. The workflow that I want to restore a previous version of is called “Check Audit Month”, so I’ll expand out that folder. Now I can see all of the files that my workflow is comprised of.
4. Each of these files has a set of versions. Right click on the XOML file, and choose **Version History**. I want to get rid of all the changes I made today, and revert back to the 4/12 version which I know worked correctly. I scroll down and click on the most recent 4/12 version. (I’ve blurred out the domain name I’m working in)
5. Click **Restore**.
6. Right click on the next file, the XOML.rules. Go find that exact same date/time of the file as the one in the previous step, and **restore it**. Note that the version number may NOT be the same.
7. Right click the next file, which is xoml.wfconfig.xml. Do the same thing by finding that same date/time that matches the one you restored at step 4. Restore it.
8. In this case, I don’t need to change anything about my InfoPath XSN file, which is the task form as part of tasks that are assigned in the workflow. I’m skipping that one.
9. Important step after you’ve restored the old versions… **EXIT SharePoint Designer.** This is because of a cached version of your workflow needing to be refreshed.
10. **Re-open your site** in SharePoint Designer. When you open your workflow in the normal way now (as opposed to the funky way we did in step 2), you will see that good old version that you just restored.
11. Click **Publish**. Now your restored workflow is live and in use on the site.

**The above solution applies to**

This solution applies to all versions of SharePoint 2010, 2007, and **SharePoint Online with Office 365**. This does NOT apply to SharePoint 2013 workflows, but DOES apply to SharePoint 2010 workflows created in SharePoint 2013.

Reference:

[SharePoint Designer – Restore Previous Workflow Version](https://www.google.com/amp/s/wonderlaura.com/2012/05/02/sharepoint-designer-restore-previous-workflow-version/amp/)

Comment: but under All files i can not find a folder named "Workflows", as shown in the screen shot i provided